# Async initialization of properties

Tags: c#, asynchronous, ref

I am trying to refactor loading individual properties with an async method.
The loader function is this:

```
public static async Task<Preferences> GetPreferences( string key ) ...
```

It is currently used like this

```
GetPreferences( "SettingsUploadStale" ).ContinueWith( task =>
    App.MayUploadStale = Convert.ToBoolean( task.Result?.Value )
);
```

I have a bunch of these calls and want to hide and reuse the ContinueWith, Convert, etc. I came up with this function

```
public static void LoadPreferenceAsync( string key, ref bool store ) {
    GetPreferences( key ).ContinueWith( task =>
        store = Convert.ToBoolean( task.Result?.Value )
    );
}

LoadPreferenceAsync( "SettingsUploadStale", ref App.MayUploadStale);
```

Which fails to compile with *"Cannot use ref, out, or in parameter 'store' inside an anonymous method, lambda expression, query expression, or local function"*.

So what is the recommended way to do this? I don't want to `await` tasks so that it can happen in background and I can load them all in parallel. Don't want to use unsafe code or pointers, because this is a `Xamarin` app and `Xamarin` is too unstable already without that stuff.

Comment: Don't use `ContinueWith`. Use `await`.

Comment: May [this tip](http://csharp.tips/tip/article/977-Using-ref%2c-out-param-in-Lambda) be useful? Place full type definition in the parameter part of the lambda, it should be ok.

Answer (score 1):

You *can* await tasks and load them all in parallel. Try

```
var taskSettingsUploadStale = GetPreferences("SettingsUploadStale");
var taskSomethingElse = GetPreferences("SomethingElse");
var taskSomeOtherThing = GetPreferences("SomeOtherThing");

Task.WaitAll(taskSettingsUploadStale, taskSomethingElse, taskSomeOtherThing);

App.MayUploadStale = Convert.ToBoolean( taskSettingsUploadStale.Result?.Value);
// get and use remaining results
```

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping for a one-liner per each property

Answer (score 0):

It is not an elegant solution and not tested but you could rewrite your function as

```
public static void LoadPreferenceAsync(string key, Action<Task<Preferences>> continueAction){
     GetPreferences(key).ContinueWith(task => continueAction);
}
```

and use it like:

```
Action<Task<Preferences>> continueAction = task => App.MayUploadStale = Convert.ToBoolean(task.Result?.Value);
LoadPreferenceAsync("SettingsUploadStale", continueAction);
```

Comment: Yeah, lambda looks like the only way